# Error 1064 (42000) in Mariadb mysql

Tags: mysql

The error is this one

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 41: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

and below is the line 41

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`user_id`,`first_name`,`last_name`,`status_input`);
```

I'm running it at mariadb mysql for linux (centOS)

Comment: You don't insert anything

Comment: Where is the rest, the values? You just seem to be listing the columns.

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `status_input` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=80 ;

Comment: Sorry to say that, but all is in this sentence: *"check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax ..."*

Comment: You are not using the correct syntax for the `INSERT` method. You can find the documentation [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/insert/).

Comment: what does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax would be

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`first_name`,`last_name`,`status_input`) VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'Talk to me...');
```

MariaDB expects values to be set when inserting something, since otherwise there would be nothing to insert. Also, I've omitted the `user_id`, since this is an `AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY` column and will be set automatically. You should not set this to a value manually, unless there is a good reason.